# How do I fix the "float cannot be converted into float[]" error in the below code?

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

I have written a small program to take number of elements from user and the price of those elements and then print the price.

But the 12th line of this code giving error "float cannot be converted into float[]", and I am not able to figure out how to resolve this. Please provide some help or any modification in the code if needed.

```
     import java.util.Scanner;
     public class Main{
     public static void main( String args[]){
     System.out.println("enter the number of elements :" );
     Scanner s1= new Scanner(System.in);
     int N = s1.nextInt();
     System.out.println("enter the price of all the elements in ascending
     order: ");
     float[] price =new float[N];

    for(int i=0; i<N;i++){
    price=s1.nextFloat();
    System.out.println(price);
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: You have to put the value into the `i`th position in price.

Comment: and to put value into `i`th position: `array[i] = ....` (`array` is the array variable and `...` represents what has to go into that position of the array)

Comment: Just do `price[i]=s1.nextFloat()`  Remember that `price` is an array of `floats`, not a `float` itself. You have to access each of its values separately.

Comment: The indentation in the code is atrocious. Please fix it. You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57239062/edit) (unlike a forum). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{

  public static void main( String args[]){

    System.out.println("enter the number of elements :" );
     Scanner s1= new Scanner(System.in);
      int N = s1.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter the price of all the elements in ascending 
    order :");

         float[] price =new float[N];

       for(int i=0; i<N;i++){

          price[i]=s1.nextFloat();
          System.out.println(price[i]);
           }

           }
}
```

It should be like this because in the printing statement you've called the whole array that won't give you the element but the some numbers and alphabets thing and also the statement where you're reading the prices by scanner you are not telling the computer to put your price at which index of the array that's why it's giving this error.

Comment: The indentation in the code is atrocious. Please fix it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Formatting and nomenclature are a must when you write code as it makes your code more readable and easy to understand. I have formatted your code and also updated for proper inputs.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("enter the number of elements :");
        Scanner s1 = null;
        try {
            s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            int totalElements = s1.nextInt();
            System.out.println("enter the price of all the elements in ascending order :");
            float[] price = new float[totalElements];
            for (int i = 0; i < totalElements; i++) {
                price[i] = s1.nextFloat();
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(price));
            }
        } finally {
            if (s1 != null) {
                s1.close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Please take care of below things:

1. Variable names should start with small case and follow camel casing.
2. Scanner whenever used needs to be closed.
3. Your error is resolved by assigning float to one position in array and not to the array. E.g. price[i] = s1.nextFloat();
4. To print an array, use the Arrays.toString() function.

Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `price` is an *array*

```
float[] price = ...
```

And an array of type T consists of elements, each of type T. So you need to assign *an element* of the array to a float e.g.

```
   price[i] = myFloat;
```